# Displaying a list as string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, parsing

I am pretty new to Python, and I am writing code for a program that queries for and displays map image ID's for satellite images.

The images are compiled into a list, and I would like to print that list as a string, with new lines between each image ID. The image ID's are saved as separate entries in the list, but when I try to do something like

```
print result
list_ = result
list_as_json = json.dumps(list_)
myBigString = "\n".join(list_as_json)
print myBigString
```

or

```
myBigString = ""
for s in list_as_json: 
myBigString = myBigString + "\n" + s
print myBigString
```

It ends up printing every letter from the ID on a different line. So, instead of printing something like:

LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160402014017EDC00 
 LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160402014033EDC00 
 LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160402014049EDC00 
 LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160412014017EDC00 
 LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160412014033EDC00 
 LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160412014049EDC00

it prints:

L 
A 
N 
D 
S 
A 
T 
/ 
L 
E 
7 
_ 
L 
1 
etc.

If I just enter

print list_as_json

I get:

["LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160402014017EDC00",
"LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160402014033EDC00",
"LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160402014049EDC00",
"LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160412014017EDC00",
"LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160412014033EDC00",
"LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE70160412014049EDC00"]

Any words of wisdom?

Comment: 1. Do not use `list` as a variable name. 2. Display the `list` contents to us also

Comment: what does your list look like?

Comment: If your `list` is `["ID1", "ID2", "ID3", ".",".","."]`, then it should work. However, I suspect your `list` to be an array of characters (instead of strings).

Comment: Show us please >> print list

Comment: I modified my question to have the exact list name I use, and to show the exact output I am getting. Also added the output when I print list_as_json. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: There is an indentation problem in your second code snippet.  I don't know if it's in your original code or just arose when you pasted it in.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python script works correct - you have a `string`, not a `list` and it iterates over chars

Show us how you create your `list` variable for more concrete help

You can try to [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) your string into list and then print it the way you do

Comment: @LYFT show please how you creates the `result` variable

Answer (score 0):

A python list should look like: `['ID1', 'ID2']`

What you see as output now is a string being printed out, character by character.

Assuming that your string looks like

```
s = 'ID1ID2'
```

You could do:

```
import re
for i in re.findall(r'\w\w\d','ID1ID2'): print i
```

To get this output:

```
 ID1
 ID2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
print repr(the_list)
```